# Window Fade in and Out

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, window

how do I fade a window in when it's opened and out when closed?

This should probably be done in Objective C. This has to be part of an AppleScript-Objective-C project. I'm using a property linked to the window, and doing makeKeyAndOrderFront on it...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subclass (or add a category to) NSWindow and add:

```
- (void)fadeInAndMakeKeyAndOrderFront:(BOOL)orderFront {
    [self setAlphaValue:0.0];
    if (orderFront) {
        [self makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
    [[self animator] setAlphaValue:1.0];
}

- (void)fadeOutAndOrderOut:(BOOL)orderOut {
    if (orderOut) {
        NSTimeInterval delay = [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] duration] + 0.1;
        [self performSelector:@selector(orderOut:) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
    }
    [[self animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
}
```

This allows you to fade in/out windows programmatically.

To have a window fade out when its close button gets pushed, add this to the window's delegate:

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender {
    [window fadeOutAndOrderOut:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

To show a window with fade-in call `[window fadeInAndMakeKeyAndOrderFront:YES];` instead of what you'd call otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! It *looks* like it should work, I get no errors when I build, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your window needs to have an alpha value of 0.0 to see the fade in. Should work now.

Comment: The functions had to be called programmatically to fade your window (and worked as such). I added a note and snippet for attaching the fade effect to the window's close button. (I also replaced [window orderFront:] with [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:], as that's what you'd probably want anyway.)

Comment: I have one BIG thing though... This has to be part of an AppleScript-Objective-C Menubar application. I'm using a property linked to the window, and doing makeKeyAndOrderFront on it, when a menu item is pressed. Any way I can fade in the window in AppleScript-Objective C?

Comment: In Applescript Studio there used to be "call method "fadeInAndMakeKeyAndOrderFront:" of foo with parameter true". Not sure if that's still the proper way though. It was, some years ago (pre-ScriptingBridge days). I'd just add a Cocoa object with "- (IBAction)showWindowWithFade:(id)sender;" though, whose only job is to handle the fading. It would then also be the window's delegate and implement the "- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender;" as seen in my answer. Your question was cocoa-only though. For calling Objective-C from Applescript you better open a new question for clearity, I think.